# mySQL How to find a name by max sum in different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm doing as  a homework a bank database.

I have two tables: "Account" and "Transactions". Account holds name, surname and acc.number of a client. Transactions holds account number where money comes from, date (rrrr-mm-dd) and amount. I need to find a client with the biggest sum of transfered money in current month.

I tried

```
Account inner join (select acc_number, sum(Ammount) as Total from Transactions group by Acc.number order by Total) on Account.acc_number=Transactions.acc_number;
```

But it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Is that your actual query, or is there a bit missing? And... Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a "select fields" from your query.
I think this query should do what you're trying to achieve.

```
SELECT SUM(Ammount),Account.acc_number from Account 
INNER JOIN Transactions ON Account.acc_number=Transactions.acc_number 
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
GROUP BY Account.acc_number 
ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```